# Changing image rotation using Javascript best practice

Tags: javascript, android, html, image, exif

I am attempting to upload an image by capturing from camera on android phone. After searching why the image shows rotated I found the reason was due to the image EXIF of the captured image. And I was wondering what is the best practice to rotating the image back to normal, is it after uploading the image or when viewing the image?
Also I need assistance in writing the JavaScript code for that given that I have an image element and file input element.

Comment: Are you using any mobile development framework?

Comment: no,I am running my page on chrome browser on android